# Factorise $x^4-7x^3y+5x^2y^2+31xy^3-30y^4$

Tags: polynomials

Factorise $x^4-7x^3y+5x^2y^2+31xy^3-30y^4$.

Can you give me a hint, I've been trying to solve this for about half an hour, still no results.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+x%5E4-7x%5E3y%2B5x%5E2y%5E2%2B31xy%5E3-30y%5E4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

1. Observe that $f(x,y)=x^4-7x^3y+5x^2y^2+31xy^3-30y^4$ is a homogeneous function of degree $4$ i.e. $f(tx,ty)=t^4f(x,y)$.
2. Use $y=tx$ and you get $f(x,y)=x^4(1-7t+5t^2+31t^3-30t^4)$.
3. In the expression, put $t=1$ and we get $f(x,y)=0$. Similarly, put $t=3$ and go on in this way. So $(t-1)$ and $(t-3)$ are factors and finally put the value of $t$.  In this way, you will get the factors.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't that many factors of $30$ in the first place so brutal force would be a good idea, especially knowing that $1-7+5+31-30=0$.

Hence after some tries we get the equation $=(x-y)(x^3-6x^2y-xy^2+30y^3)=(x-y)(x-3y)(x^2-3xy-10y^2)=(x-y)(x-3y)(x-5y)(x+2y)$